# How to open Outlook Calendar from an email link or webpage?

Tags: php, javascript, email, outlook, calendar

Is it possible to open Outlook Calendar from an email link or a webpage?
I am looking for code that will open the recipient's Outlook Calendar. I don't want to populate the calendar with anything - just open Outlook Calendar so they themselves can block out some time.

Comment: No, save for sending an event if have configured to be opened with the calender, you cannot control what programs open on my computer, unless with some java of activex applet perhaps with very high permissions, which would only be suited for an intranet, because no one in his right mind would give an untrusted page/applet those permissions.

Comment: I'm going to go with a .ICS file with a tentative date/time that the recipient can change as I can't create a .ICS file without those parameters.

Answer (score 6):

On the condition that outlook is installed on the client, you can use the following syntax:

```
<outlook:calendar>
```

(as the link)

Other links include:

To Open a Specific Item

```
<Outlook:Contacts/~Itemname>
```

To open the contact fred blogs, type the following:

```
<Outlook:Contacts/~fred blogs>
```

To open an Item in a Public Folder

```
<Outlook://Public Folders/Foldername/~Itemname>
```

For example, to open a contact named, "John Doe" in a plublic folder named, "Public Contacts" use the following hyperlink:

```
<Outlook://Public Folders/Public Contacts/~John Doe>
```

To open a file in a Public Folder

```
<Outlook://Public Folders/Foldername/Mydocument.doc>
```

Note: In the above example Word will open the document file. You do not need to proceed the file name with a tilde since it is not an Outlook item.

To Open an Item in a Subfolder of a Folder in Your Inbox

```
<Outlook:Inbox/Foldername/Subfoldername/~Itemname>
```

To open New Labor Time, located in the Labor folder in your Inbox, type the following:

```
<Outlook:Inbox/Labor/~New Labor Time>
```

Comment: Good answer! Two notes: first of all, since Outlook 2007 said links only work inside Outlook, not from a webpage (Outlook url protocol is no longer registered these days). Second, the syntax is the classic <a href="outlook:calendar">bla</a>.

Comment: Hi, I tested this on a couple of systems running both outlook and it seemed to still work. However, your solution is a good one and I'll note that for future reference. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Rendition's answer is terrific and covers the grand majority of links. I just wanted to add one more because it took me a while to figure it out.

When it comes to public folders, [in the past](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/225007) it was possible to just address them directly, for example:

```
outlook://Public Folders/All Public Folders/TeamA/ItemName
```

However in Outlook 2010 and beyond, it seems you have to specify the recipient's email as well (see this [MS knowledge-base article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2470828))

For example:

```
outlook://Public Folders - Joe.Blogs@company.com/All Public Folders/TeamA/ItemName
```