# HTML link to Outlook Meeting Room Calender

Tags: html, email, outlook, calendar

Is it possible to have a HTML link that opens Outlook and views the Resource Calender for a specific meeting room?

I have read [How to open Outlook Calendar from an email link or webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282248/how-to-open-outlook-calendar-from-an-email-link-or-webpage), but the great answer from **Rendition** only briefly covers the outlook's calender function (`<outlook:calendar>`) and I am still not sure if it works outside an HTML email on a true web page.

thx!