# How to open Outlook Contact or Calendar from an email link or webpage?

Tags: outlook

Is it still possible to use Outlook URLs to open Open Outlook items such as Calendars or Contacts as per the below article...

[How to open Outlook Calendar from an email link or webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282248/how-to-open-outlook-calendar-from-an-email-link-or-webpage/66778719#66778719)

Comment: I can get folders to open but not specific Contacts, if I run the following reg file with contents...

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\outlook]
"URL Protocol"=""
@="URL:Outlook Folders"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\outlook\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\PROGRA~1\\MICROS~2\\root\\Office16\\OUTLOOK.EXE,1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\outlook\shell]
@="open"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\outlook\shell\open]
@=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\outlook\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\PROGRA~1\\MICROS~2\\root\\Office16\\OUTLOOK.EXE\" /select \"%1\""

Answer (score 0):

If you register the Outlook protocol like described in the [Shortcuts and the Missing Outlook:// Protocol](http://www.slipstick.com/problems/outlook-missing-outlook-protocol/) article you can open items.

You can link to a globally unique identifier (`EntryID`) that is created for an item and doesn’t change when you rename or move it:

```
Outlook:000000000EAE44133243899468AC478B31C0BANDHEWR324
```

It is best to use the GUID URL since you don’t have to worry about changes breaking the link. If you are after a outlook message, all you have to do is select that message in outlook, and then left-click on the linker icon on the lower right of the taskbar so that the link will get copied. Next, you will just have to paste it somewhere. It works the same way for contacts and even calendar events.

Comment: Thanks Eugene.  I don't know how to get the EntryID for Contacts and Calendar items in Microsoft Outlook 365.

Comment: See [EntryID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.entryid)